# Numba cc export with numpy functions not working

Tags: python, numpy, compilation, numba

I just started using numba and i would like to compile a code for later use according to this tutorial :
https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/pycc.html

I get problems while trying some functions on my own. First, it says on the website that you can omit the type of the output and when i try this function (same as the webiste but without the f8 for the output) :

```
@cc.export('square', '(f8)')
def square(a):
    return a ** 2
```

I get : TypeError: invalid signature: '(f8)' (type: 'str') evaluates to 'Float' instead of tuple or Signature

But i get no problem doing this (Take away the output type for a function with 2 different inputs) :

```
@cc.export('multf', '(f8, f8)')
@cc.export('multi', '(i4, i4)')
def mult(a, b):
    return a * b
```

First question : What am i doing wrong here?

Also, i tried running a function on my own and i'm having trouble working with numpy arrays. The function i would like to compile is :

```
@cc.export('VolumeTetrahedra', 'f8[:,:](f8[:], f8[:], f8[:], f8[:])')
def VolumeTetrahedra(a, b, c, d) :
    return abs(1/6 * np.linalg.det(np.asarray([[a[0], b[0], c[0], d[0]],[a[1], b[1], c[1], d[1]],[a[2], b[2], c[2], d[2]],[1,1,1,1]])))
```

Which uses numpy functions (i checked and numba website says these functions should work, unless i read something wrong)

I simply get this error :
AssertionError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: native lowering)

So basically, if i understand correctly, numba tries to execute without using python to go faster and it can't do this with this function so it gives me an error, i just can't find a way to introduce array into numba without getting this type of error, is there a way to compile my example function or a function that would do the same?

If someone could help me solves my numba problems, i would apreciate it,

Thx, Tanjay

Answer (score 0):

#### Q1: What does *TypeError: invalid signature: '(f8)' (type: 'str') evaluates to 'Float' instead of tuple or Signature* mean?

The problem here is that brackets around one element in python don't do anything. They don't make it a tuple with 1 element. If you replace `'(f8)'` with `'(f8,)'` it works just fine.

#### Q2: What's wrong with my VolumeTetrahedra function?

First of all

```
from numba.pycc import CC

cc = CC('my_module')
@cc.export('VolumeTetrahedra', 'f8[:,:](f8[:], f8[:], f8[:], f8[:])')
def VolumeTetrahedra(a, b, c, d) :
    return abs(1/6 * np.linalg.det(np.asarray([[a[0], b[0], c[0], d[0]],[a[1], b[1], c[1], d[1]],[a[2], b[2], c[2], d[2]],[1,1,1,1]])))
```

works just fine on my machine. By which I mean I can run it without getting an exception. I am running numba version 0.54.0.

But it looks really odd to me. First of all numba is not going to speed up pure numpy. And then your numpy code looks odd. Why not just do

```
abs(1/6*np.linalg.det(np.concatenate([np.stack([a,b,c,d]).T, np.array([1,1,1,1]).reshape(1,-1)])))
```

Comment: Hello! Thx for your answear! #1 is perfect, for #2, first off i want the volume of a tetrahedron caracterized by 4 points in 3d space. The formula i am using can be found here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Volume with the special case that d doesnt equal 0. I was running on numba 0.54.1 but even when i downgrade to your version (0.54.0) it doesnt run on my system. Any idea what could cause this (I am using conda version on windows)? Also, i had other stuff in the functions to run but i narrowed it down to where the problem was, it won't be pure python in the end.

Comment: @Tanjay Have you tried running exactly the code that I claim works? Also my point was that it's not useful to compile this using numba since it doesn't speed up pure numpy code.

Comment: Yes i tried running exactly what you sent me but it wont compile, i don't get an error but it fails and gives me a "^" before the line where i return the output. Also, i understood what you meant when you said this part wont be faster but this part is part of a bigger function that contains code which will be faster using numba, this part is simply the part where it wont compile, so i rewrote it as the question.

Comment: @Tanjay That's odd. For me it not only compiles but if I give in vectors also calculates the volume. Maybe a numba/numpy bug.

Comment: I dont know why but every time i write a line of code that containts np.asarray() or np.array() it wont compile for some reason...? It always stop there without an error message, just a "^" at the corresponding line of code.

Comment: @Tanjay yea I don't know how to help with that. Maybe make a new topic with examples of that.